# Cannot create new object for Ruby on Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

simple question.  I'm trying to create a new object for a very basic class

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :title, :content

  validates :title,  :presence => true
  validates :content, :presence => true
end
```

However, when I try to create a new object in the console, the title and content fields always show up as nil

```
1.9.2-head :021 > a = Article.new(title: "abcdefg", content: "hijklmnop")
 => #<Article id: nil, title: nil, content: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Why can't I create a new object?

Comment: Try with `Article.create!(title: "abcdefg", content: "hijklmnop")` . The `!` will display errors as to why the creating that object failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Were you trying to use `attr_accessible`?

Comment: @Jazear By using `attr_accessor` instead of `attr_accessible` you are over-riding the default rails setter/getter and hence the value you are setting in the constructor is ignored.

Comment: Correct, thanks.  I guess now I need to create specific setter methods if I want to change the content of these objects

Comment: Or better, delete the call to attr_accessor and use the generated setters and getters unless you have reason to do otherwise.